# Define a relation R on N by setting aRb if a|b or b|a. Is R an equivalence relation?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, elementary-set-theory, logic

I am not very familiar with this so I hope my attempt is good enough. I think it is not an equivalence relation. 
We need this relation to be reflexive, transitive and symmetric. 
I 'think' it is symmetric since we can switch the order of 'or'. 
Trivially reflexive, for all a, a|a. 
Now we try to prove it is transitive as if 
'a|b or b|a' and 'b|c or c|b' implies 'a|c or c|a' 
Case 1: a|b and b|c -> a|c
Case 2: a|b and c|b this does not imply aRc 
Case 3: b|a and b|c this does not imply aRc 
Case 4: b|a and c|b -> c|a
So in cases 2/3 it doesn't hold so it is not an equivalence relation. 
Many thanks.

Comment: A counterexample for the transitivity would be much simpler: consider $2, 6,3$, for instance.

Comment: @ClementC. actually I would say it is *necessary*, +1.

Comment: Note that when you write "this does not imply aRc," you state it (and it's true), but you haven't technically proven it... (@AndreasCaranti indeed, you're right.)

Comment: Sorry but,why would it be necessary?

Comment: It is necessary because if the same relation is defined, say, on the subset of $\mathbb{N}$ consisting of the powers of two, it would be (rather trivially) an equivalence relation. So the set where it is defined makes a difference.

Comment: Ah, hence why I need a counterexample in N.

Comment: Thank you very much guys. :)

Comment: That's it, exactly!

Answer (score 1):

Vaguely mentioned in the comments, but I want to make it very clear that you can only claim a statement is **false** if you **prove** a counter-example. If you are unable to prove a statement, it does not imply that it is false! There are some statements that cannot be proven but also cannot be disproven, and so cannot be considered true or false in an absolute sense.

However, your reasoning is indeed the best way to find a counter-example. You know exactly which case you must have to cause transitivity to fail, namely $a \mid b$ and $c \mid b$ but $b \nmid a$ and $b \nmid c$. You also want $a \nmid c$ and $c \nmid a$, so $a,c$ must each have some prime factor not shared by the other. This easily suggests trying $a = 2$ and $c = 3$, and it is easy to find $b$ that works.